Data augmentation strategies when there is a difference in image resolution between train and test set
I am doing transfer learning Resnet34 for an object detection problem. My dataset has around 9500 observations, 20 classes. I tried the basic augmentation such as: horizontal flip, gaussian noise, colorjitter, random rotation,... Currently, my model accuracy is around 84% on validation set but I want to improve the model's accuracy to 95%.
At first, I tried a more complex model, but because of my small dataset, a complex model tends to overfit even before it reaches my current best accuracy. I realized that the test images I was given have lower resolution (64x64) compared to my train images (100x100, 200x100,...).
If this helps, I currently unfreeze 2 last layers of resnet and all batchnorm layers for finetuning. My batch_size is 64 and I trained for 50 epochs. I has also experimented with weight_decay, dropout rate but this mostly helps with overfitting problem. It does not improve my accuracy much.
What strategies could I use to improve my model's accuracy here? Thank you.
